# bootstrap alert from server side

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm a newbie. I need to be shown a notification using bootstrap when executing server code. only the written code works for me. I do not know how to call a notification when executing code.

```
static MessageBox()
        {
            // Create the store
            pageTable = new Dictionary<Page, Queue>();
        }

        public static void Show(string str)
        {
            // Lets find out what page is sending the request
            Page page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;

            // If a valid page is found
            if (page != null)
            {
                // Check if this page is requesting message show for the first time
                if (pageTable.ContainsKey(page) == false)
                {
                    // Lets create a message queue dedicated for this page.
                    pageTable.Add(page, new Queue());
                }

                // Let us add messages of this to the queue now
                pageTable[page].Enqueue(str);

                // Now let put a hook on the page unload where we will show our message
                page.Unload += new EventHandler(page_Unload);
            }
        }

        static void page_Unload(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Lets find out which page is getting unloaded
            Page page = sender as Page;

            // If a valid page is found
            if (page != null)
            {
                // Extract the messages for this page and push them to client side
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write
                    ("<script>alert('" + pageTable[page].Dequeue() + "');</script>");
              
               
            }
        }
```

but this is a standard page notification.
the call occurs as follows

```
    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" id="LinkButton1" cssclass="badge badge-pill badge-info" commandargument='<%#Eval("tabel")%>' commandname="tabel">tur</asp:LinkButton>
MessageBox.Show("test message");
```

Comment: i am not sure which version of net you are using.  but for this type of server side notifications it is common to use SignalR or RabbitMQ.... or some other message broker.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it really depends on the bootstrap dialog or say "toast" message you looking to display.

For a pop dialog (say confirm to delete), I find jQuery.UI gives you  MUCH more control. (and you can control the location of the pop dialog).

For a "message" notificaiton, then I suggest say jQuery toast.

So, in this form for example, I have a delete button. And in fact the WHOLE form was popped as a dialog from the grid view behind:

[image]

Then when I clicked on the delete button, I poped another dialog to confirm the delete.

The code to pop that delete dialog was a js routine. And if it returns true, then the server side button runs, and if false, then the server side button code does NOT run.

The button code looked like this:

```
        <button id="cmdDelete" runat="server" class="btn myshadow" style="margin-left:15px"
            type="button"
            onserverclick="cmdDelete_ServerClick"
            onclick="if (!MyConfirmDel(this)) {return false};"  >
            <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"> Delete</span>
        </button>
```

So, I have both a server side event (plane jane .net code).

And I have a client side event - JavaScript.

So, the js routine MyConfirmDel(this) runs the client side js code, and that was this:

```
       var MyConfirmDelOK = false
       function MyConfirmDel(Btn) {
           if (MyConfirmDelOK) {
               MyConfirmDelOK = false
               return true
           }
           var myDialog = $("#mydelpop");
           myDialog.dialog({
               title: "Delete Hotel",
               width: "26em",
               modal: true,
               dialogClass: 'ui-widget-shadow',                   
               position: { my: "left top", at: "right bottom", of: Btn },
                buttons: {
                    Delete: function () {
                        myDialog.dialog('close')
                        MyConfirmDelOK= true
                        $(Btn).click()
                    },
                    cancel: function () {
                        myDialog.dialog('close')
                    }
                }
           });
       }
```

But, maybe by notification you mean a toast message:

So, when I for example hit this button, I get a pop dialog to confirm (works like above), and then I trigger a toast message.

I have BOTH routine setup to pop dialogs from the server side code, and also a toast message routine that shows a notification as jquery toast.

This example:
[image]

the server side code to pop the notification is this:

```
Protected Sub cmdReSet_ServerClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    MySqlExecute("exec MyRestore")

    GridView1.DataBind()

    MyToast(Me.Page, cmdReSet.ClientID, "Data Restored", "Data re-set back to original", "6000")


End Sub
```

And MyToast routine is this that injects the js routine to run.

```
Sub MyToast(my As Page, ctrlBeside As String, Heading As String,
            strText As String,
            Optional strDelay As String = "3000")

    ' same as Mytoast, but a js function called toastcall()
    ' MUST be placed on the page
    ' any master page will have this function
    ' ctrlBesite - do NOT pass # - so Button1 you pass "Button1"

    Dim strScipt As String =
        "toastcall('@ctrlBeside','@Heading','@Text','@strDelay');"

    strScipt = strScipt.Replace("@ctrlBeside", ctrlBeside)
    strScipt = strScipt.Replace("@Heading", Heading)
    strScipt = strScipt.Replace("@Text", strText)
    strScipt = strScipt.Replace("@strDelay", strDelay)


    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(my, my.GetType(), "mytoast", strScipt, True)

End Sub
```

So, it not clear if  you looking for a pop dialog or confirm dialog to be triggered from server side code, or a toast like notification that you want to display, and use server side code to do this as per above.

If you want say a "working - please wait" notification, then I suggest the above toast message. (set the toast message to much longer then the processing routine). when your code behind is done, then the page life cycle is completed, and the toast message will go away without any additonal code.

So, attach a client side and server side event to the one button. You click,  and the client side toast message will appear, and THEN your server side code runs. When done, with a post-back cycle complete, then as noted, the toast message, or even dialog message will go away on its own.

I love the look and feel of the bootstrap dialogs, but they are a royal pain to position on the form, and even more of a pain to easy pop with js code, so I used jquery.UI dialogs as a result. You get MUCH better control in code, but as noted, I don't particular like the look and feel of the jQuery.UI dialogs - they look somewhat dated.

so you can as the above toast message routine shows, EASY trigger a message from the server side, but it going to occur AFTER the button code (server side) processing is done. If you need the toast message to appear at button click time, then you HAVE to trigger that with client side code.

I suppose you could use server side code, but you would have to:

```
 load up - set the js routine to run + display - allow page code to complete

 then in js code, display message, and then trigger another post back
```

In this case, as noted, better would be to have a client side message event appear, and then have the client side js code THEN call a web method. When the web method is done, then upon return from the web method call, you can close your dialog. This approach is probably the best, but you you wanting to trigger this from code behind, the you have to split this out into two routines:

```
First routine - trigger js code (like I did for toast)
```

That first routine ALSO THEN can call a web method while the message is display, and when done, hide message.

So, you can't for example place both the "please wait" and have a long running process occur in the SAME routine (code behind). (the exception I suppose would be adopting SignalR -- which is quite a big system and adopting for what amounts to the goal of a simple message is over kill).